# Subir archivo al servidor más un parámetro adicional

Tags: java, android, fileupload

Tengo en mi aplicación una función para subir ficheros al servidor, esta función funciona de maravilla, pero tengo la problemática que junto al fichero tengo que mandar un parámetro extra llamado **objeto** , mi pregunta es : que cambio tendría que hacerle a mi función de subir el archivo para que también mande el otro parámetro.

Función que utilizo para subir el fichero

```
    public void uploadFile(){
    try {
        Log.e("Service","se ejecuto");
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile =  new UtilHelper().Compress(activity,command,profileBitmap,"");
        String sourceFileUri = new UtilHelper().genString(activity)+".zip";

        if (sourceFile.isFile()) {

            try {
              //  String upLoadServerUri = "https://apretaste.com/run/app";
                String upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.137.1/demo/u.php";

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE",
                        "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("file", sourceFileUri);



                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());


                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\""
                        + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math
                            .min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,
                            bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file
                // data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                        + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    String line;
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    /*Gson gson = new  Gson();
                    HttpInfo httpInfo;
                    httpInfo = gson.fromJson(result.toString(),HttpInfo.class);

                    if (httpInfo.code.equals("200")){
                        Log.e("link descarga",httpInfo.file);
                        downloadFile(httpInfo.file);
                    }*/
                    Log.e("respuesta",result.toString());


                }

                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {


                e.printStackTrace();

            }


        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

PHP que recibe los datos

```
<?php


 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
$uploads_dir = './upload/';
                        $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                        $pic_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$pic_name);

                            echo "subido";
                        }
           else{
               echo "File not uploaded successfully.";
       }

       echo $_POST['objeto'];
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Usa el método [setRequestProperty (String key, 
                String value)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) de `HttpURLConnection`:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("objeto","valorDeObjeto");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder , pero eso lo había intentado antes y no funciona , usted lo ha probado ?

Comment: Imposible probar sin tener acceso a la aplicación a la que quieres conectarte. ¿Cómo es la función del servidor que recoge el fichero?

Comment: ```<?php
 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    $uploads_dir = './upload/';
                            $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                            $pic_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$pic_name);
                          
                          echo "subido";
                            }
               else{
                   echo "File not uploaded successfully.";
           }

           echo $_POST['objeto'];

   ?>```
Esta es la función que uso..

Comment: ¿Y dónde se recoge ahí el parámetro "objeto"? Copia esta información, y dale formato, en la pregunta.

Comment: fijate que estoy haciendo un echo con el parámetro , actualice la pregunta , se ve mejor..